# Big-O Notation Advice

Tags: big-o, discrete-mathematics

Which of these functions is not *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>)?

A. *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>log<sub>2</sub>*n*)

B. *O*(log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>*n*)

C. *O*(*n*log<sub>2</sub>*n*)

D. (log<sub>2</sub><sup>*n*</sup>)<sup>2</sup>

I believe, that it is not A, because *n*<sup>2</sup> takes dominance in that one, which would make it a *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) as well.

My question becomes how do you figure out which one is not a *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>)? I have not worked much with logarithms, and I am still fuzzy about how to work with them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is A

Big-O is an upper bound and in programming represents the worst-case runtime. For example f(n) = n^2 means f(n) is O(n^2) and O(n^3) and O(n^100*logn). So O(n^2) is also O(n^3) but O(n^3) is not O(n^2)

In the case of your question, the only answer that is > n^2 is A. Graphing the functions can help you visualize it. As you can see A (red) is the only one increasing faster than n^2 (black)
[image]

This article may help you as well
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation and go to Orders of common functions

Comment: so what you are saying is that in the case of this question, you are looking for a equation that grows faster than the given one.  All ones that grow slower could also be Big-O of n^2?? but being that n^2 is an upper bound then if it grows faster it definitely can't be a big O of n^2?

Comment: Yes. B,C,D are all O(n^2) as they are upper bounded by n^2. With A, O(n^2) is a lower bound (not upper)

Comment: One other question I had was if I were sorting Big O's so that each is a Big O of the next,  Could I just graph each and if the graph is higher than the other than that would mean it grows faster than the other?

Comment: In this case yes. Sometimes complex functions can appear higher in the graph at first but at y = 1000000 it crosses. You're basically looking at which one is higher if it goes to infinity.